# Label polygons in an atlas with similar attributes to the mask layer

Tags: qgis, labeling, atlas

I have two similar vector layers, with the same attributes. One is multipart and I used it as mask for the atlas, the other one is single parts and I want to use it to label the polygons inside each multipart polygon.

I have tried with the rule based labeling with this filter

within($geometry, @atlas_geometry)

But it only works sometimes.

[image]
This works

[image]
This one not.

I tried to check all the label condictions, and I tried to do it with centroids to ensure that the point was inside the polygon of the mask, but no way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use only the multipart vector layer to make your atlas AND for the representation.

In the layers properties you symbolise the vector on this rules-based:

```
$id = $atlasfeatureid
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the multipart layer have not the info I want to show in the label... I want to show the label of each part and that was combined when I created the multipart layer.

Comment: I think that i confused single and multiplepart. Have you tri this solution with single part?